# R if statement across columns of data table to populate new column

Tags: r

```
data <- data.frame(dates = c("2014-10-28 00:01:59.526","2014-10-27 13:30:01.526"),
                   times = c("23:59:59","13:29:55"),
                   hour = c(23,13),
                   minute = c(59,29),
                   second = c(59,55))
data[,1] <- as.POSIXct(data[,1])
data[,2] <- as.factor(data[,2])
class(data[,1])
class(data[,2])
class(data[,3])
class(data[,4])
class(data[,5])
      data

                    dates    times hour minute second
1 2014-10-28 00:01:59.526 23:59:59   23     59     59
2 2014-10-27 13:30:01.526 13:29:55   13     29     55
```

I need to populate a new column "NewDate" with a POSIXct data that is the combination of the date and time column BUT there IF the hour column shows 23 then the date for "NEwDate" should be the date from the "date" column  MINUS 1 day otherwise it should be the date from the "date" column.

So the final output should be:

```
             date           time     hour   minute second  NewDate      
1 2014-10-28 00:01:59.526   23:59:59   23    59     59  2014-10-27 23:59:59 #NewDate =  date-1 + time
2 2014-10-27 13:30:01.526   13:29:55   13     29      55  2014-10-17 13:29:55 #NewDate = date + time
```

(NewDate has to be a POSIXct)

What is the best way to do this WITHOUT looping down the data frame and doing something like:

```
library(lubridate) #lubridate contains hour(), minute(), second()

CorrectTIME <- function(date, hour, minute, second)
{
  NewDate<- vector("numeric",length(date))
  for(i in 1:length(date))
  {
        if(hour[i] > hour(date[i]) ) 
        {
          NewDate[i] =ISOdatetime(year(date[i]), month(date[i]), day(date[i])-1, hour[i], minute[i], second[i], tz="GMT")
        }else
        {
          NewDate[i] =ISOdatetime(year(date[i]), month(date[i]), day(date[i]), hour[i], minute[i], second[i], tz="GMT")
        }
  }

}
```

Comment: R has a function for that: `?ifelse`

Comment: The as.factor was superfluous. It was already a factor.

Answer (score 0):

```
with(data, paste ( format( as.Date(dates) - (hour == 23) , "%Y-%m-%d"), 
           paste( hour, minute, second, sep=":")))
#[1] "2014-10-27 23:59:59" "2014-10-27 13:29:55"
```

Ooops, forgot the as.POSIXct:

```
as.POSIXct( with(data, paste ( format( as.Date(dates) - (hour==23) , 
            "%Y-%m-%d"),  paste( hour, minute, second, sep=":"))) )
[1] "2014-10-27 23:59:59 PDT" "2014-10-27 13:29:55 PDT"
```